# Instagram client was disabled

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have registered an app and it has been working fine for more than one month, but suddenly I received "This client was disabled for violating the Instagram Platform Policies" message and my app was disabled.
http://img.newtonideas.com/asvjlnajahb8asnbckcq.png

I reported this as an issue by pressing a "Report Issue" button on 
 "Manage Clients" page: http://img.newtonideas.com/9bndwkbiolm4botw4aes.png 
Still, passed 2+ weeks without any reply. Do you know how can we get know a reason of disabling the app?

Comment: No way to know, other than carefully reading the Policy document. Can you think of no rule your app might have broken?

Comment: @Andrii Dobrainskiy in the end did Instagram responde back? I am in the same sittuation and for over a week, no news from their side. Thank you

Comment: @Alin, still no reply. We created a new Instagram app and I hope that it will not be disabled again.

Comment: @AndriiDobrianskiy thank you for your time and answer. So basically they've approved your new client? Did you change anything in the app before doing a new permission review process?

Comment: @Alin, actually, we have fixed privacy policy URL (it became broken when we moved from http to https)

Comment: @AndriiDobrianskiy but you've made a new client with the same name as the disabled one and you submitted again for permission review process?

Comment: @Alin, yes, and it was approved by Instagram team